# TestFlight tab doesn't load in iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

When I switch to the TestFlight tab for my app in iTunes Connect, it doesn't load. It perpetually shows the spinner.

It was doing this yesterday too. I've tried a different browser and it's the same.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing the same, it appears to be down. Hopefully they fix it soon, as it is the only place to manage your test flight apps.

Answer (score 1):

You guys hit your rate limits apparently.  You will have to wait a couple hours and it will work.  Most ridiculous thing ever.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide **supporting info** as to why they're the best.  Answers should be self-contained so explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links as supporting information can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review